# Autofocus on input elements inside a tab-group

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there a way to set autofocus on an input elements inside a mat-tab elements inside of a mat-tab-group? 
Current behaviour is that focus is set to the first tab's label.

I tried writing a directive that sets a deferred focus on the element, but that only works if the timeout is high enough > 500ms, hoever this doesn't seem like a good choice.

Is there a way to prevent the mat-tab-groups from grabbing the focus? I believe this has something to do with accessability but in my case it's just very unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `selectedTabChange` event, it should work fine:

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="focus($event)">
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Content 2</mat-label>
            <input matInput #input>
        </mat-form-field>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>


focus(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that did not do the trick. it even throws an error, because element in the focus function seems to be undefined :- \

Comment: I didn't look at the code closely. The event object will be a MatTabChangeEvent object - anything else you need you'll have to work out for yourself.